# How can I resolve an unauthorized error when using Azure Management API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-management-api

How can I resolve an unauthorized error when using Azure Management API?

Note:
I would prefer to resolve this programmatically (in code) instead of running commands/scripts.

**Objective:**

I need to retrieve function names from a Function App in Azure.

Example:

```
  var current        = Pulumi.Azure.Core.GetClientConfig.InvokeAsync().Result;
  var subscriptionId = current.SubscriptionId;
  var appName        = functionApp.Name;

  var url = $"GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appName}/functions?api-version=2022-03-01";

  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var result     = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

  if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception($"Error: Failed to retrive Azure function names from {appName}");

  var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Thoughts:**

I think I need to create a bearer token but do not know the steps required.

Comment: This may help,  Authenticate using a Service Principal, https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/installation-configuration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got same error as below:***

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appName}/functions?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to generate bearer token for the service principal and include it in headers section with **Authorization** parameter.

I registered one Azure AD application in my tenant like this: *Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration*

[image]

Now, create one **client secret** in that application and copy its `value` like below:

[image]

Make sure to assign proper role based on your requirement. I assigned **`Reader`** role to the above service principal under my subscription like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

In my function app, I created one HTTP function named **SriHTTP** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got the **results** successfully when I used the above token to call management API like below:

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appName}/functions?api-version=2022-03-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I receive a gran_type error when attempting to post using PostMan. What authorization type do I use in PostMan on the Authorization tab?

Comment: Are you getting that grant_type error while acquiring token? Can you include the snip of Postman once to know what exactly the issue is?

Comment: {
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: some_guid\r\nCorrelation ID: some_guid\r\nTimestamp: 2022-12-28 12:00:17Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],

Comment: I assign the value "client_credentials" to grant_type.

Comment: If you are passing the parameters under **`Params`** or any, instead of **`Body`** section, you may get [**error**](https://i.imgur.com/7AuzBUY.png) like this.

Comment: Make sure to pass them under [**Body section**](https://i.imgur.com/z7aqbyF.png) by selecting `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250705/discussion-between-sridevi-and-scott-nimrod).